# Inconsistent solr index on dse cluster

Tags: solr, cassandra

We have a cluster of 9 nodes with RF of 3 and search is enabled on all nodes. We face a problem of inconsistent result set on Solr and Cassandra. When I count documents on Cassandra using Spark I got 250M documents and when querying solr I got 190M.

How can I resolve this issue on inconsistency of data?